# Cannot find module '@schematics/angular/utility/json-file' when installing angular universal

Tags: angular, npm, angular-universal

This error occurs when trying to install Angular Universal by executing `add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject [project name]`.

I am using Angular 7. I tried running `npm install @schematics/angular@7.2.0`, but it didn't work.

What might be causing this to fail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This command works for `same` angular and express-engine versions: `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine@^7.1.1 --clientProject project-name`

To get an idea you can refer this:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14002

Comment: Yes, this worked for me. Indeed it was 7.1.1